# Reason to explicitly cast from char to int in Java?

Tags: java, casting

I have seen in Java code in many places, people tend to cast between primitives int and char.

Is this necessary? Are they not implicitly converted.
For e.g. I tried this and exactly got what I should. Then why do people explicitly cast? Am I missing something?

```
char a = 'a';
int index = (int) a;
index = 98;
a = 98;
System.out.println(index);
System.out.println(a);
```

Comment: Because it's a hardwired/habitual operation? But no, that cast is useless - Java will automatically widen from `char` to `int` (and `int` to `long`, etc).

Comment: Useful additional info to all this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sometimes people will cast for clarity, sometimes for overloading reasons, and sometimes for reasons of ignorance.

For example:

```
System.out.println((int) a);
```

will work differently to

```
System.out.println(a);
```

due to overload resolution. But in the exact code you've given, it's definitely not required. If you want to know exactly why a particular developer has chosen to write redundant code, you'd need to ask them...

Comment: +1 for showing the case of when the explicit cast may be important.

Answer (score 0):

Casting in this case removes ambiguity, and makes the code easier to read.

Comment: In this case I don't agree; the type of the variable is readily apparent. In other cases, perhaps.

Comment: You're right. In this case, like Jon said, it is just ignorance.